# How can I run a shell command in vim and return the resulting string into a VimScript variable?

Tags: shell, vim, subprocess, fork

How can I do this extremely simple operation in vim?

```
let g:string_from_shell = run_in_shell('awk ...')
```

(command use for exposition only)

Comment: Apologies if this seems rather basic, I've been looking around looking for how to do this, and simply can't find anything.

Comment: "Looking around" where? All the functions available are listed in `:help functions`.

Comment: I think the downvote is quite unfair. If you don't know what to look for it's quite difficult to find what you're looking for. I spent a while googling around for this. While I'm familiar with the `:help` command, it's not instinctive for many Vim users to use because it can be dense and vast. Other than that, what's wrong with the question?

Comment: You are looking for an hypothetic `run_in_shell()` function so you are supposed to browse the list of available functions at `:help functions`. Simple as that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `system` function to execute system/shell commands in vim. Then, you can store its output to a vim variable.

Syntax :

```
  :let variable = system("shell command")
```

You can check its output by printing the variable like

```
  :echo variable
```

Example:

```
  :let list = system("ls -ltr")
  :echo list
```

To know more about it, give `:help system()` in command line.

Comment: Note that you may want to trim/chomp the trailing newline.

Comment: Trailing newline in?

Comment: `system()` returns a string terminated by a '\r' (or `\n`, I never remember which). Depending on what we want to do next, this extraneous character needs to be removed/ignored. See `:echo system('echo "foo"')."#"`